# Making the Bootstrap navbar searchbox work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a search function which works if I put in the query params into my URL directly but I don't know how to make it work so that it picks it up from the search box and executes it. I have used ng-model to map the text itself to the controller which works but the execution isn't working.

The navbar form:

```
<form ng-submit="doSearch()" class="navbar-form">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 input-group" style="display:table;">
            <input ng-model="search.text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

By the way, my **doSearch()** function works just fine when I run it manually and so is the search itself. I have also validated that search.text comes through. I guess what I am asking is how do I make the icon (**glyphicon-search**) execute **ng-submit="doSearch()"** when the user clicks on it or presses enter.

Sorry if this is very obvious. I was always more on the backend side of things so am sorta new to HTML and Angular.

Thanks

Comment: Can you privode us the code of your `doSearch()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked in the end. First, the proper HTML which works:

```
<form ng-submit="doSearch()" class="navbar-form">
<div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 input-group" style="display:table;">
        <input ng-model="search.text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
            <span ng-click="doSearch()" class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Furthermore, there was an issue with the view not connecting to the controller. Actually, let me rephrase that - it was connecting to the controller but only when the whole page loaded and for my test, I had a console.log('I have loaded') put in there. So when I saw "I have loaded", I thought my controller was invoked properly.

However, the doSearch() was in the controller which was connecting via angular routing, so the ng-View was not connecting to the right controller.

I am not sure if this means anything to anyone but I am writing this in case someone else comes across an issue like mine.

So just to summarise the issue was not with the HTML as I originally thought. ng-submit (for form submission when pressing enter) and ng-click (for clicking the glyphicon) does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the icon inside a `<button>` element instead of `<span>`, tweak a bit of css to integrate it to the form field.

In regards to trigger search on enter, with jQuery something like this could be used:

```
$('input').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
    doSearch();  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in Angular you could do this natively. My answer will explain how my whole thought process to troubleshoot this issue was flawed. I will, however, note this down as I am sure it will come in handy for my project. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

did you try using   `<button type="submit">` before your search icon
    `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>`
to specify that clicking on that button is equivalent to a submit event for that form.